# Terms Aggregations of fields

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, querydsl

I am in process to read the data from metrics and want to read selected one on latest datetime. I use Aggregations to get top one but failing somewhere as result given by query not match with latest. May be I am lacking somewhere. This is my final query

```
var elasticResponse = elasticClient.Search<object>(s => s
                .Aggregations(ag => ag
                    .Terms("cpu_aggs", sa => sa.Field("system.cpu.total.pct").Size(1))
                    .Terms("memory_aggs", sa => sa.Field("system.memory.actual.used.pct").Size(1))
                    .Terms("diskio_aggs", sa => sa.Field("docker.diskio.summary.bytes").Size(1))
                    .Terms("load_aggs", sa => sa.Field("system.load.5").Size(1))
                )
                .Sort(so => so.Descending("@timestamp"))
            );
```

Please help to find correct solution.

Updated solution is

```
.Terms(currentMemoryUsageInPercent, sa => sa.Field("system.memory.actual.used.pct").Size(1).Order(o => o.Descending("max_timestamp"))
                .Aggregations(agg => agg.Max("max_timestamp", mx => mx.Field(greoupByFieldName))))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you try to achieve?

Aggregation is a groupby

```
.Aggregations(ag => ag
                     .Terms("cpu_aggs", sa => sa.Field("system.cpu.total.pct").Size(1))
                     .Terms("memory_aggs", sa => sa.Field("system.memory.actual.used.pct").Size(1))
                     .Terms("diskio_aggs", sa => sa.Field("docker.diskio.summary.bytes").Size(1))
                     .Terms("load_aggs", sa => sa.Field("system.load.5").Size(1))
                 )




.Terms("cpu_aggs", sa => sa.Field("system.cpu.total.pct").Size(1)



 Means you want the most (and only because of the size(1) system.cpu.total.pct in your data 
    then
```

`.Terms("memory_aggs", sa => sa.Field("system.memory.actual.used.pct").Size(1))` 
    => the most system.memory.actual.used.pct value
        ect

```
All these aggregation are at the same level, so you will have most reccurent pct, most recurent memory, more recurent bytes ect...Each of these aggregations is independant and will scan all your document.



    Your sort is not apply to aggregation, it will be apply to your query, by default, 10 documents are returned, so it will return the last 10 documents.
```

Aggregation are done to make analyse betweebn different documents (reccurence, mean, max, count, sum...).

For exemple, what you can do:

first, if you only want to work with aggregation, dont ask for document, put a .Size(0).

```
var elasticResponse = Client.Search<object>(s => s
                .Size(0)
                 .Aggregations(ag => ag
```

If you want to make aggregation on a field, to get for exemple the 10 more reccurent value:

```
.Terms("cpu_aggs", sa => sa.Field("system.cpu.total.pct").Size(10)
```

If you want the 10 more reccurent of "system.cpu.total.pct" with the last document for each of them

```
.Terms("cpu_aggs", sa => sa.Field("system.cpu.total.pct")).TopHits("topcpu", r => r.Field("@timestamp").Sort(ss => ss.Descending()).Size(1)))
```

If you want the 10 more reccurent "cpu_aggs", and when for each of this top cpu value the 5 top "system.load.5"

```
.Terms("cpu_aggs", sa => sa.Field("docker.diskio.summary.bytes").Size(10)
                        .Aggregations(subag => subag.Terms("subaggr", sua => sua.Field("system.load.5").Size(5))
                     ))
```

if you want stats (if system.cpu.total.pct is a number for exemple)

```
.Stats("cpu_stats", sa => sa.Field("system.cpu.total.pct"))
```

---

If you only want the last document, you dont need aggregation:

```
var elasticResponse = elasticClient.Search<object>(s => s
                .Size(1)
                .Sort(so => so.Descending("@timestamp"))
            );
```

If this dont answer to your question, please clarify, and join some example of what you need.

Comment: Thanks LeBigCat for your time and suggestion.

Comment: Actully I want the latest value of selected metrics like "system.memory.actual.used.pct" etc from all the documents. I was thinking to get it by Aggregation. Suggest what would be best approch?

Comment: The soution which you provide   ```.Terms("cpu_aggs", sa => sa.Field("system.cpu.total.pct")).TopHits("topcpu", r => r.Field("@timestamp").Sort(ss => ss.Descending()).Size(1)))``` gives error - elasticsearch parsing_exception unknown key for a value_string in [field]